# Mix ref links and functions with an @click in a Vuetify Drawer

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In a Vuetify Drawer I have a

```
 <v-list-tile
              v-for="(child, i) in item.children"
              :key="i"
              v-on:click.stop="goPage(child.ref)"
              @click="{{child.ref}}"
            >
```

and in my children I have

```
  children: [
          {
            icon: "contacts",
            text: "Application",
            type: "link",
            ref: "/trainee/application/",
            role: "trainee"
          },
```

Is there a way that I can redirect the @click of a child item so that ref does not call a link but instead calls a function?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition inside click event like below

```
<v-list-tile
    v-for="(child, i) in item.children"
    :key="i"
    @click="onClick(child)"
>
```

And add new `onClick` method

```
methods: {
    onClick(child) {
        if (/* condition */) {
           // call function here
        } else {
            this.goPage(child.ref);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you-- This helps alot